# C++ reading a mathematical function and sorting

Tags: c++, arrays, string, algorithm, vector

I'm reading a function from a file in the format f(x,y,f(x),g) once I read the input it is stored as a vector and I am trying to get each value between the commas so in this case i want to get x, y f(x) and g as separate chars/strings. I'm stuck, any ideas?

Comment: What part are you stuck on? Have you done any research on parsing?

Comment: I've tried reading after the first '(' until the comma but the code only ran once and stopped after the first comma because of my loop. Here is what I tried: <html>for(int i = found_para1 + 1; i< comma; ++i){
            letter = left_side[i];
        if(letter != ',' ){
            value += letter;
        }</html>

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

//Split string into vector of strings
vector<string> split(string str, char delimiter) 
{
  vector<string> internal;
  stringstream ss(str); // Turn the string into a stream.
  string tok;

  while(getline(ss, tok, delimiter)) 
  {
    internal.push_back(tok);
  }

  return internal;
}

int main()
{
  string myInput = "f(x,y,f(x),g)";

  //Extract the string between outer brackets
  size_t startIndex = myInput.find_first_of("(") + 1;
  size_t endIndex   = myInput.find_last_of(")");
  string innerStr   = myInput.substr(startIndex, endIndex-startIndex);

  //Split the result by comma
  vector<string> sep = split(innerStr, ',');

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sep.size(); ++i)
  {
     cout << sep[i] << endl;
  }

}
```

Hope it helps